# Using "foreach" in string array c#

Tags: c#, for-loop

Good Morning,

I need a foreach loop to print the sequence below line by line:

loop1 a0,a1,a2

loop2 b0,b1,b2

loop3 c0,c1,c2

This is my first post, so sorry for any lack of information.

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int col0_int = 0;
            var col0_elements = new string[] { "a0", "b0", "c0", "d0", "e0", "f0", "g0", "h0", };
            IList<string> col0_all = col0_elements;
            String[] col0_list = new String[col0_all.Count];

            List<string> col0_each = new List<string>();

            foreach (string element in col0_elements)
            {
                col0_list[col0_int++] = element;
                col0_each.Add(element);
            }

            int col1_int = 0;
            var col1_elements = new string[] { "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", };
            IList<string> col1_all = col1_elements;
            String[] col1_list = new String[col1_all.Count];

            List<string> col1_each = new List<string>();

            foreach (string element in col1_elements)
            {
                col1_list[col1_int++] = element;
                col1_each.Add(element);
            }

            int col2_int = 0;
            var col2_elements = new string[] { "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2", };
            IList<string> col2_all = col2_elements;
            String[] col2_list = new String[col2_all.Count];

            List<string> col2_each = new List<string>();

            foreach (string element in col2_elements)
            {
                col2_list[col2_int++] = element;
                col2_each.Add(element);
            }
           //LOOP script here
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What issues are you having? What errors do you get? What isn't working? Please help us narrow it down so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: Why are you creating a duplicate array and a list with the same values for each of the 3 arrays?

Comment: How to do want it to print (message box alert or print it in console)? im assuming you are using winform ?

Comment: I'm using this way to collect data from different pages by Selenium .. there was no error, but the way I was doing the print was just pulling a0, b0 and not a0, a1 as I wanted.. print in messagebox.. tks for all comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all arrays are equal length:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < col0_list.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{col0_all[i]},{col1_all[i]},{col2_all[i]}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that your three lists always contain the required elements at the correct position, a fast solution would be to use the LINQ [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) extension method two times:

```
var results = col0_elements.Zip(col1_elements, (x, y) => $"{x}, {y}")
                           .Zip(col2_elements, (x, y) => $"{x}, {y}");
```

This produces an `IEnumerable<string>` (over which you can loop) with the following content:

```
{
    "a0, a1, a2",
    "b0, b1, b2", 
    "c0, c1, c2", 
    "d0, d1, d2", 
    "e0, e1, e2", 
    "f0, f1, f2", 
    "g0, g1, g2",
    "h0, h1, h2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating the things.
For each string array you are creating an empty string array and a list with only one element...
With this approach you are esentially creating a string matrix.

```
var col0_elements = new string[] { "a0", "b0", "c0", "d0", "e0", "f0", "g0", "h0", };
var col1_elements = new string[] { "a1", "b1", "c1", "d1", "e1", "f1", "g1", "h1", };
var col2_elements = new string[] { "a2", "b2", "c2", "d2", "e2", "f2", "g2", "h2", };

IList<string[]> all_elements = new List<string[]>{ col0_elements, col1_elements, col2_elements };

for (int i = 0; i < col0_elements.Length; i++) // Row iteration
{
    foreach (var cell in all_elements) // Cell iteration
    {
        Console.Write(cell[i]);   
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get those with a for loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < col0_each.Count; index++)
{
    string col0String = col0_each[index];
    string col1String = col1_each[index];
    string col2String = col2_each[index];

    (print as desired);
}
```

This code doesn't include any error checking to make sure each list is long enough; it assumes they are all the same length.

There are extra lists in the code that could be simplified, though that's not what you asked about.